# jquery div scrolling position

Tags: jquery

Can someone help me to understand what makes left panel on the blog post autoscroll? With social links

http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/nomination-judge-the-net-magazine-awards/

maybe plugin?

if not tutorial link will be helpfull..

want this effect sooo much.

Comment: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/stickyfloat
http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/

Comment: Try this jQuery plugin http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/ Simple and easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar tutorial here: http://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/

Answer (score 1):

It is simply done with a little JavaScript. The links are set to be positioned absolute and then a JavaScript function sets the top of the menu to be level with the scroll position of the window if the scroll position is below a certain level. This might be done with an interval so the JavaScript can check regularly the position of the scrollbar.

So something like the following would help, bit of CSS and JavaScript(jQuery):

```
#menu {position:absolute;}

setInterval(function(){
    // All the code to find out where to put the menu goes here. for instance:
    $('#menu').css({top: $(window).scrollTop()});
}, 10);
```

This isn't a working example, just an example of the technique. But as you said I am sure you can find a plugin through google.

Comment: Doing this in `$(window).scroll` would be nicer and cleaner.

Comment: Yes it probably would. When I started writing the answer I wasn't going to use jQuery and that was the solution that sprung to mind. But yes that would be better.

Comment: Thank you guys! Now i have the point to start! I really appreciate your answers!

Comment: if someone will need plugin i found one =)